# what is contract type in solidity and what is the use of it

Tags: solidity, contract-development

```
    contract DappToken {
        string  public name = "MDV";
        string  public symbol = "$$$";
        string  public standard = "DApp Token v1.0";
        uint256 public totalSupply;
        // having more code 
    }
```

I have Imported the These contract in my next file  and used the the contract name as the name of the variable

```
contract DappTokenSale {
    address admin;
    **DappToken public tokenContract;**
    uint256 public tokenPrice;
    uint256 public tokensSold;

function DappTokenSale(DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
    admin = msg.sender;
    tokenContract = _tokenContract;
    tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
}
}
```

In migrations we passed the the addess of the deployed contract to the token contract

```
function DappTokenSale(DappToken _tokenContract, uint256 _tokenPrice) public {
    admin = msg.sender;
    tokenContract = _tokenContract;
    tokenPrice = _tokenPrice;
}
```

1) Why do we even have to declare a varable a contract type  here

2) We know it is the address we are going to pass so why can't we declare a address type insted of contract type

3) What is diffrence between defining a varble a  contract type and some data type

4) I have observed the same behaviour in interface  defining the interface type before the varable initlization

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you cast a variable as an `address` you get the methods of an address, such as `.send()` and `.tranfer()` ETH.

When you can a variable as contract, you get the methods that are encoded in the contract functions, such as `myContract.doSomething(args)`

You can convert from a contract to an address. For example, to print the contract address in an event log.

`address a = address(myContract);`

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Rob 

But every erc20 token  has a tranfer method written  in the code. It means  your transfer method will override the  default  tranfer ,Which  we use to transfer ether  

2) If not how your methods will excute without overriding

Comment: You are correct. `address.transfer()` is ethereum address method to transfer ETH. `contract.transfer()` is a contract method implemented in code.

Comment: The `contract.transfer ()` method potentially does anything. In an erc20 it would normally be concerned with the token only. "Transfer token" instead of "transfer eth."

Comment: Thanks  Rob

sorry for bothering you more   

if i buy  the erc20 token i can transfer erc20 token as well as the ether to some account (how it is possible if the default method is override ) if possible how it  knows whether we are calling erc20 transfer or default transfer

Comment: Send ETH is protocol layer - from: me, to: receiver, amount: eth. Send token is a contract execution. from: me, to: contract, data: {address: receiver, uint: amount}. That "syntax" is pseudo. It takes many forms depending on your layer of abstraction. Deep down, one is telling ethereum to move ETH and the other is sending a message to a contract.